# Spark Streaming Kafka integration in CDH 5.8.3 in yarn-cluster mode

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

I'm facing a weird issue in running a Spark Streaming job reading from Kafka. I'm on a CDH 5.8.3 distribution: Spark version is 1.6.0 and Kafka version is 0.9.0.

My code is very simple:

```
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("bootstrap.servers" -> brokersList, "auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest")
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, Set(kafkaTopic))
```

If I run it in **yarn-client** mode I have no error. While if I run the program in **yarn-cluster** mode I am getting an Exception. My launching command is:

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --files /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml --num-executors 5 --executor-memory 4G --jars (somejars for HBase interaction) --class mypackage.MyClass myJar.jar
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: kafka.cluster.Broker cannot be cast to kafka.cluster.BrokerEndPoint
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$6$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:90)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:87)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:86)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1.foreach(Set.scala:74)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:85)
at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.findLeaders(KafkaCluster.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getLeaderOffsets(KafkaCluster.scala:179)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getLeaderOffsets(KafkaCluster.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getEarliestLeaderOffsets(KafkaCluster.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$$anonfun$5.apply(KafkaUtils.scala:213)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$$anonfun$5.apply(KafkaUtils.scala:211)
at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:211)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:484)
at myPackage.Ingestion$.createStreamingContext(Ingestion.scala:120)
at myPackage.Ingestion$$anonfun$1.apply(Ingestion.scala:55)
at myPackage.Ingestion$$anonfun$1.apply(Ingestion.scala:55)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.getOrCreate(StreamingContext.scala:864)
at myPackage.Ingestion$.main(Ingestion.scala:55)
at myPackage.Ingestion.main(Ingestion.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:542)
```

Surfing the internet I ended thinking that it's a version issue, but I can't figure out why this happens, since the jars are the same running both in yarn-client and yarn-cluster mode.

Do you have any idea?

Thank you,
Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might encounter the same issue, our problem was due to the Splice Machine installation. Indeed, Splice Machine requires to set its jars in YARN additional jars configuration (and among them there is also a spark-assembly by them).

Now we're trying to find out a way to make all the things running without unisntall Splice Machine from our cluster.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a way to do this in a less obtrusively with Splice Machine. It is just not something that has been chased all the way down. In a direct path to make [only] Splice Machine work the documentation dictates that one must add the splice and hbase lib directories to the YARN application classpath (In CM).  This is great for Splice Machine, but can cause issues for other applications running in YARN -- as evidenced by this post.  The solution is most likely to remove the additional YARN application classpath entries, and push those classpath settings elsewhere in the Splice Machine config.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Spark streaming 1.6 is compatible with Kafka 0.8 (see [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/streaming-programming-guide.html#advanced-sources))

I'd guess you're using Kafka client 0.9, which gets picked up in **client** mode from your jar, but when you switch to **cluster** mode default Kafka client (0.8.2.1) is used.

Am I right? If so, can you try removing kafka client dependency from your build and use default one provided by `spark-streaming-kafka`? (0.8 client should work with 0.9 brokers).

Comment: dear Arkadiusz, we found the issue. The reason was that we installed Splice Machine which requires to set its jars in YARN additional jars configuration (and among them there is also a spark-assembly by them). Now we are talking with them to understand how to solve this issue. I tried to delete the question but unfortunately I am not able to, because of the bounty.